# Highlighting alphabets in dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I ceated a dropdown in angular js which appears when i write something in my input textbox and filter is also applied to input textbox such that only dat value appear in dropdown which matches my text in input textbox. Now i want to hightlight those alphabets in dropdown which i've written in input text box

Comment: I think a plunker or jsfiddle of your existing code would help here. Let us see what you have so far. Am I correctly understanding that you are filtering your dropdown on the basis of partial matches to the text in your input, and you now want to highlight the portion of each dropdown item that matched?

Comment: yes, i want to highlight that portion of dropdown which matched with the text i wrote in input textbox like if i wrote 'i' in input textbox..and in dropdown i got india,indonesia as the results then i want to highlight 'i'

Comment: Okay. There are probably a couple ways to do that, and which makes the most sense will depend on your implementation so far. Show us that, and we'll be better able to help.